# Automatically add scripts and styles in angular.json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular-library

My goal is simply to add the scripts and styles automatically in angular.json using the command line.For example if I am installing bootstrap in my angular project using the following the command.

```
npm install bootstrap
```

I have to manually goto angular.json and add the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js .

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",

        ]
```

Is there a way to do this with a command ? The reason why I need this because i am using my custom library and have its dependencies installed.Since custom libraries dont have any angular.json , the custom library gets installed but could not figure out a way to add the scripts and styles.

Comment: So for your own library? There is some mechanism for that, which is interpreted by the [ng add](https://angular.io/cli/add) command.

Comment: yes i need this for my own library..that library has dependencies such as bootstrap,jquery which i have mentioned in the librarie's package.json..Dependencies successfully gets installed when i am adding in the main project..but the scripts and styles could not be added dynamically to the main project..so I am looking for any command that could help me

Comment: TLDR; Perhaps this is what you're looking for: [Making an Addable Angular Package](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/making-an-addable-angular-package-using-schematics/)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to add the script on the src/index.html file for it to be always bundled.